# What is the difference between Function Callback and ISR?

Tags: embedded-linux, embedded-resource

I am programing UART and I need to access the Transmission or reception using interrupts. However I was bit confused about ISR and function Callback for recption or transmission specifically in ARM architecture?

Comment: A callback function is an OS construct.  It has no processor or architectural dependencies.  Interrupts and the ISR do have to conform to the hardware requirements.  I.E. kkrambo's (in the referenced post) and my comments reflect the mainstream concept of "callback function".

Answer (score 0):

As baonn describes in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25093767/how-is-isr-a-callback-function),

A bit of setup code stores the address of the ISR function in the interrupt vector table to say "call me back at this address when the interrupt occurs".

To be clear, the ISR itself is the function that is "called back". The interrupted code is not the callback; it is merely "interrupted" and later "resumed".

On ARM Architecture, [This link](http://www.raspberry-projects.com/pi/programming-in-c/uart-serial-port/using-the-uart) might be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

A callback is a function pointer (i.e. address) that is passed to another piece of code.

An Interrupt Service Routine (ISR) is a function which runs when an hardware interrupt is triggered.

An Interrupt Service Routine (ISR), also known as an Interrupt Handler, is a special kind of callback that takes no input parameters and returns nothing.

ISR handlers are triggered by hardware interrupts. Interrupt handler 'callbacks' are not called directly by software (at least not normally).
The addresses of interrupt handler 'callbacks' are stored in an interrupt vector table.

This may be worth a read:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt_handler
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt_vector_table
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)